# Sonicwall IKE Initiator drop

Tags: vpn, nat, sonicwall

I am trying to resurrect a once working VPN between two Sonicwall devices.
The branch office is the initiator and sends the request, the main office drops the packets and signals an error:

```
IKE Initiator drop: VPN tunnel end point does not match configured VPN Policy Bound to scope
```

Have you seen this error before? Can you suggest what to do about it?

More details on the configuration.
I assume nothing has changed on the main office configuration. I have changed things in the branch office.

The branch office has two local networks, a local one for the office devices (printer etc) and a second one for the VPN. It has only one public IP on the modem/router/all in one. The Sonicwall manages the VPN but has to go through the local network out to the modem.

```
                    =----= printer, wifi
modem+LAN(10.X.X.X) =----= X1-Sonicwall-VPN-X0 (192.168.X.X) =--= Tunnelling PCs
```

The modem is doing NAT for the local network, and the Sonicwall is doing NAT for its own network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer the question about the error, however, what solved the problem for me was adding a new NAT rule to translate traffic directed to the WAN port of the Sonicwall and point it to the VPN.

With this setup, tunnelling PCs can send connect to the VPN and to the local network.

Comment: You should accept this answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up and looking for an answer.